# Nested Json in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

Looks like when I try to put this loaded json into a DataFrame, I'm getting results like so

```
Url = "URL I'm getting json from"
Url_instance = Br.open(url)
Results = json.load(url_instance)
Frame = pd.DataFrame(results)
Print Results
```

I apologize for the poor syntax, I'm asking this question via phone.

The json looks like:

```
{u'failCount': 0, u'child': [{u'name': 'TestOne'}, {u'name':'TestTwo'}]}
```

Results

```
     child                               fail
0   {u'name': u'TestOne'}     0
1   {u'name': u'TestTwo'}     0
2.  {u'name': u'TestThree}    0
```

I want to try get the names and the related fail counts in the frame correctly.

What's a good approach for solving this problem? I've tried dropping the the column from the current frame and merging it with a new frame using ['child'] but wasn't able to do it correctly.

Comment: I would suggest adding "this JSON" as well as how you are loading the JSON into the question so we can better help you.

Comment: Can you give a partial example of the json input?

Comment: I just added some examples. Sorry I'm on my phone.

Comment: A DataFrame is a tabular representation of data and is not well suited to an arbitrary JSON string.  If you knew the structure of the JSON, you could create a DataFrame using MultiIndex, but the JSON structure would need to be fixed.  Why do you want to load the data into a dataframe.  What is your real objective?

Comment: I'm writing results from an API to an excel spreadsheet and it's much easier to do it via DataFrame vs XLWT because there are a lot of them. I was able to find a work around for my problem by framing the child column individually and creating a new frame for the remaining columns. Then piecing them together. I think you're right though, I'll need a better understanding of the json, so I can multiIndex.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite Results:

```
output = {u'failCount': 0, u'child': [{u'name': 'TestOne'}, {u'name':'TestTwo'}]}

new_output = {}

for item in output:
   if item == 'child':
       values = list()
       for value in output[item]:
           values.append(value['name'])
       new_output['name'] = values
   else:
       new_output['failCount'] = output[item]

print new_output

{'failCount': 0, 'name': ['TestOne', 'TestTwo']}
```

You could run into some issues here with data not matching correctly. I am writing this based solely off the example you provided.